# Get the latest Object from List based on one property in the object

Tags: java, collections

Say I have a Pojo

```
public MyTask {
    TaskType taskType;
    id taskId;
    ...
}
```

The value of `taskType` can only be from the following `Enum`:

```
public static enum TaskType {
    WRITE_DOC, UPDATE_DOC, SEND_DOC, OTHER
};
```

Now I have a **List** of `MyTask`:

```
List<MyTask> tasks = GOT_TASKS_FROM_SOMEWHERE();
```

The above **List** of `MyTask` contains multiple tasks of random task type from the Enum mixed together. Some tasks in the list could have same `TaskType` too.

I need to create a function, which takes one `TaskType` as parameter, and returns the **latest** matching task from above task list:

```
public MyTask getLatestTaskOfType(TaskType type){
   //I am not sure how could I get the latest MyTask with the TaskType 
}
```

How can I get the latest `MyTask` from the **List**(`tasks`) which matches the `TaskType` in parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse iterate your list and the first object you find with the required type is the result :

```
ListIterator<MyTask> reverseIterator = tasks.listIterator(tasks.size());
while (reverseIterator.hasPrevious()) {
   MyTask task = reverseIterator.previous();
   if (task.getTaskType() == type)
      return task;
}

return null; // Not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand correctly. You have a list of MyTask objects and you want to retrieve the last element in the list that has a specified TaskType. You could go for a reverse iteration of the list, or you could add elements at the beginning of the list and iterate it normally. Another solution would be to use a LinkedHashMap for your data structure. With this kind of structure, retrievals should be fast and it will maintain the insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

you can have one more field in `MyTask` for update time to store. say it 'lastupdated'.

now in below method

```
public MyTask getLatestTask(TaskName name){
   //iterate tasks list and prepare new list of tasks matching taskname = name
   // sort new list with comparator which compares list w.r.t 'lastupdated' value in desc order
   // return first  element from sorted list, which is the last updated task matching your criteria
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You could have a `public final` date object which is initialized to the current date and time.
- Or you could also update the id sequentially, in which case, the object with the max id will be the latest one.